# R how to restrict the names that are in scope to those I create explicitly?

Tags: r, scope, environment

I thought that it would be enough to use fully qualified names to avoid polluting my scope with names I did not explicitly introduce, but apparently, with R, this is not the case.

For example,

```
% R_PROFILE_USER= /usr/bin/R --quiet --no-save --no-restore
> ls(all = TRUE)
character(0)
> load("/home/berriz/_/projects/fda/deseq/.R/data_for_deseq.RData")
> ls(all = TRUE)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> ?rlog
No documentation for ‘rlog’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??rlog’
```

So far, so good.  In particular, as the last command shows, the interpreter knows nothing of `rlog`.

But after I run

```
> d <- DESeq2::DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = a, colData = b, design = c)
```

...then, henceforth, the command `?rlog` will produce a documentation page for a function I did not explicitly introduce into the environment (and did not refer to with a fully qualified name).

*I find this behavior disconcerting.*

In particular, I don't know when some definition I have explicitly made will be silently shadowed as a side-effect of some seemingly unrelated command.

How can I control what the environment can see?

Or to put it differently, how can I prevent side effects like the one illustrated above?

Comment: From `?\`::\``: "The package namespace will be loaded if it was not loaded before the call, but the package will not be attached to the search path."

Comment: @alistaire: Thanks for the calrification.  This is going to take some getting used to...  Everywhere else I've encountered the notion of a search path, it means that an unqualified identifier that cannot be found through the search path is undefined, period.  In my example, however, `rlog` is neither a qualified identifier nor, as your excerpt implies, is it reachable through the search path, and yet the R interpreter does not treat it as invalid.

Comment: There are actually a few search paths; the ones relevant here are loaded namespaces and attached namespaces. Unless prefixed with a package reference, you can only call functions that are in an attached namespace; what's loaded ordinarily won't matter much. However, `?` is greedy, and searches all loaded namespaces. `??` is greedier yet, and searches all installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if "scope" means the same thing in R as it may to other languages. R uses "environments" (see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html for detailed explanation). Your scope in R includes all environments that are loaded, and as you have discovered, the user doesn't explicitly control every environment that is loaded.

For example,

```
ls()
```

lists the objects in your default environment '.GlobalEnv'

```
search()
```

lists the currently loaded environments.

```
ls(name='package.stats')
```

In default R installations, 'package:stats' is one of the environments loaded on startup.

By default, everything you create is stored in the global environment.

```
ls(name='.GlobalEnv')
```

You can explicitly reference objects you create by referencing their environment with the $ syntax.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
.GlobalEnv$x
```